# Setup for email server for windows 8

Tags: java, email, hmail-server

My goal is to setup an environment for a locally hosted email server to handle sending and receiving of emails and i need to send the emails via java, i was reading up on stmp, pop imap. The system i am using is windows 8 and it does not have any internet access so all is done locally.

My requirements are that i need to create an environment for 2 mail servers A and B, A needs to send an email to B, and B will reply it has received the mail.

But i still am confused where to read up regarding this? i hope to get some guidance on this.

I looked at hMailserver, is this what i am looking for?

Comment: I managed to setup hmailserver and use thunderbird to locally send and receive email, so is there a way to do the sending n receiving in java itself?

Comment: hi..could you please explain how you tested hmailserver using thunderbird...i need to do the same

Comment: @VineetVerma just follow these steps http://peterkellner.net/2012/03/11/how-to-setup-your-own-pop3imap-email-server-for-local-development-testing/

Comment: Is there a way to send the mail from local mail server to external world like Gmail/Yahoo..??